# Doing ctypes.memset as of Python 3.11?

Tags: python, ctypes, cpython

I'm implementing a memset function that's supposed to set a bytes object buffer to zero.

As of Python 3.11 the buffer api functions [PyObject_GetBuffer() and PyBuffer_Release()](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#c.PyObject_GetBuffer) are now part of the Stable ABI.

The below code works, but:

- It feels strange that I have
  to define my own Py_buffer class. Isn't there one predefined
  somewhere?
- Am I using PyBuffer_Release correctly?

```py
def memset(bytes_object):
    import ctypes

    # Define the Py_buffer structure
    class Py_buffer(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('buf', ctypes.c_void_p),
            ('obj', ctypes.py_object),
            ('len', ctypes.c_ssize_t),
            ('itemsize', ctypes.c_ssize_t),
            ('readonly', ctypes.c_int),
            ('ndim', ctypes.c_int),
            ('format', ctypes.c_char_p),
            ('shape', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ssize_t)),
            ('strides', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ssize_t)),
            ('suboffsets', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ssize_t)),
            ('internal', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ]
    
    buf = Py_buffer()
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyObject_GetBuffer(ctypes.py_object(bytes_object), ctypes.byref(buf), ctypes.c_int(0))
    try:    
        ctypes.memset(buf.buf, 0, buf.len)
    finally:
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyBuffer_Release(ctypes.byref(buf))


obj = bytes("hello world", "ascii")
print("before:", repr(obj))
memset(obj)
print("after:", repr(obj))
```

Gives this output:

```
before: b'hello world'
after: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

For reference, here's an older way of doing memset on a buffer that uses the [deprecated PyObject_AsCharBuffer](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/objbuffer.html) function. It still works as of Python 3.11 though:

```
def memset_old(bytes_object: bytes):
    import ctypes

    if not isinstance(bytes_object, bytes):
        raise TypeError(f"expected bytes, not {type(bytes_object)}")

    data = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)()
    size = ctypes.c_int()
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyObject_AsCharBuffer(ctypes.py_object(bytes_object), ctypes.pointer(data), ctypes.pointer(size))
    ctypes.memset(data, 0, size.value)


obj = bytes("hello world", "ascii")
print("old before:", repr(obj))
memset_old(obj)
print("old after:", repr(obj))
```

Comment: `bytes` objects are immutable. So why???

Comment: @MarkTolonen bytes objects are indeed defined as immutable in the language. But this makes them mutable. It's done to erase encryption keys from memory.

Comment: It violates Python immutability and could have unintended side effects. If the reference count is 1 it could be safe.  Why don’t you use `bytearray` instead? Then you could clear them with Python.

Comment: @MarkTolonen All the big encryption libraries for python use bytes objects. I know the specific use case isn't a good idea. But the question of how to use memset with 3.11 and onwards still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It feels strange that I have to define my own `Py_buffer` class. Isn't there one predefined somewhere?

`Py_buffer` isn't defined anywhere but in the `pybuffer.h` header in the Python `include` directory.

> Am I using `PyBuffer_Release` correctly?

Yes, but it is good practice to define `.argtypes` and `.restype` so `ctypes` can do typechecking on arguments.  Also as noted `bytes` object buffers are meant to be read-only, so altering it is undefined behavior.

Full example with typechecking:

```py
import ctypes as ct

PyBUF_SIMPLE   = 0
PyBUF_WRITABLE = 0x0001

class Py_buffer(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('buf', ct.c_void_p),
                ('obj', ct.py_object),
                ('len', ct.c_ssize_t),
                ('itemsize', ct.c_ssize_t),
                ('readonly', ct.c_int),
                ('ndim', ct.c_int),
                ('format', ct.c_char_p),
                ('shape', ct.POINTER(ct.c_ssize_t)),
                ('strides', ct.POINTER(ct.c_ssize_t)),
                ('suboffsets', ct.POINTER(ct.c_ssize_t)),
                ('internal', ct.c_void_p))

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Display representation of a buffer.
        '''
        return f'Py_buffer(obj={self.obj!r}, readonly={self.readonly})'

# Explicitly define arguments and return values so ctypes can typecheck.
PyObject_CheckBuffer = ct.pythonapi.PyObject_CheckBuffer
PyObject_CheckBuffer.argtypes = ct.py_object,
PyObject_CheckBuffer.restype = ct.c_int
PyObject_GetBuffer = ct.pythonapi.PyObject_GetBuffer
PyObject_GetBuffer.argtypes = ct.py_object, ct.POINTER(Py_buffer), ct.c_int
PyObject_GetBuffer.restype = ct.c_int
PyBuffer_Release = ct.pythonapi.PyBuffer_Release
PyBuffer_Release.argtypes = ct.POINTER(Py_buffer),
PyBuffer_Release.restype = None

def memset(obj):
    if PyObject_CheckBuffer(obj):  # ensure object passed supports the buffer interface
        buf = Py_buffer()
        try:
            # PyObject_GetBuffer  can throw an exception if it fails.
            PyObject_GetBuffer(obj, ct.byref(buf), PyBUF_SIMPLE)
            print(buf) # View resulting buffer
            ct.memset(buf.buf, 0, buf.len)  # zero it
        finally:
            PyBuffer_Release(ct.byref(buf))

obj = b'hello, world!'
print("before:", repr(obj))
memset(obj)
print("after:", repr(obj))
```

Output:

```
before: b'hello, world!'
Py_buffer(obj=b'hello, world!', readonly=1)
after: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```